# How can I handle the order for float elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here is my code:

```css
.wrapper {
    border: 1px solid red;
    padding-left: 20px;
}

.table {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}

.table > div {
  display: table-cell;
  border: 1px solid green;
  min-width: 190px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .table > div {
  float:left;
}
  .author, .editor{
     clear: both;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">    

<div class="table">
  <div class="share_edit_flag">
    <span>share</span>
    <span>edit</span>
    <span>close</span>
  </div>

  <div class="editor">
    <a href="#">edited May 21 16 at 11:58</a>
    <div class="profile">
      <img src="#" />
      <a href="#">Rory O'Kane</a>
      <b>12.6k</b>
      <!-- I don't have any badge in my website -->
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="author">
    <a href="#">asked May 21 16 at 11:51</a>
    <div class="profile">
      <img src="#" />
      <a href="#">vasanthkumarmani</a>
      <b>1</b>
      <!-- I don't have any badge in my website -->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

</div>
```

Please run the snippet code above as full size and then resize the screen. When you reduce the screen size, you will see both `author` and `editor` boxes jump down under each other. Ok all fine.

Currently as you see, the order *(up to down)* of boxes is `editor` at first and `author` is under it. Now I want to make it vice versa. I mean, I want to put `author` box in the top of `editor` box. How can I do that?

**Note:** I want to keep the current order in the full screen size *(the author box should be rightmost)*

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use flexbox instead of floats. With flexbox and `order` property it is very easy to achieve:

```css
.wrapper {
    border: 1px solid red;
    padding-left: 20px;
}

.table {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 100%;
}

.table > div {
  border: 1px solid green;
  min-width: 190px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .author {
      order: 1;
  }
  
  .editor {
    order: 2;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">    

<div class="table">
  <div class="share_edit_flag">
    <span>share</span>
    <span>edit</span>
    <span>close</span>
  </div>

  <div class="editor">
    <a href="#">edited May 21 16 at 11:58</a>
    <div class="profile">
      <img src="#" />
      <a href="#">Rory O'Kane</a>
      <b>12.6k</b>
      <!-- I don't have any badge in my website -->
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="author">
    <a href="#">asked May 21 16 at 11:51</a>
    <div class="profile">
      <img src="#" />
      <a href="#">vasanthkumarmani</a>
      <b>1</b>
      <!-- I don't have any badge in my website -->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the `order` with flexbox.

```css
.wrapper {
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding-left: 20px;
}

.table {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}

.table > div {
  display: table-cell;
  border: 1px solid green;
  min-width: 190px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .table {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  .author {
    order: -1;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">

  <div class="table">
    <div class="share_edit_flag">
      <span>share</span>
      <span>edit</span>
      <span>close</span>
    </div>

    <div class="editor">
      <a href="#">edited May 21 16 at 11:58</a>
      <div class="profile">
        <img src="#" />
        <a href="#">Rory O'Kane</a>
        <b>12.6k</b>
        <!-- I don't have any badge in my website -->
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="author">
      <a href="#">asked May 21 16 at 11:51</a>
      <div class="profile">
        <img src="#" />
        <a href="#">vasanthkumarmani</a>
        <b>1</b>
        <!-- I don't have any badge in my website -->
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```